# Sound port at the back doesn't work in Xubuntu (tough 'puzzle')

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, realtek

I did something stupid: I forgot to connect my sound boxes at the back (= at motherboard) during the installation and now the sound doesn't work there.
With alsamixer, I can get music out at my front audio port (headset or boxes), witch is apparently for listening L and R together.
But I can't get nothing out from the back. I did the bars up and all at open ("00"). I tried different stuff at Volume Control (pulseaudio): "Headphones (plugged in)", "Speakers (Unavailable)", Analog Stereo Duplex, Analog stereo output,...
In the past, I was able to configure it so that I had sound from both at the same time, witch was handy due to the on/off button on the boxes! :-)

At windows, I had also no audio from the back too but I removed the sound driver to reinstall it again with boxes connected and it was solved.

For my Xubuntu, I tried: "https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-no-sound-issue-ubuntu/" but it doesn't work.

It sounds like there is no electricity at that port when I plug it in.

I have Realtek stuff on the motherboard. It worked before at the same Linux.

Any ideas for this tough 'puzzle'?

Answer (score 0):

OOOH, I found it: I had to put it in in the other audio back port for a little while, to activate the beeper apparently as weird wave pattern output. Then, I had to put it back to the usual audio back port to hear then sound from there (line out plugged in,Analogue stereo Duplex).

After restart, it doesn't work again and I don't know how to fix it. :s
Oh, I launched this:
amixer -c0 sset 'Auto-Mute Mode' Disabled
nice.

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. After the waiting period accept your answer by clicking on the grey check ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will help others. If you want to add new information about the question, don't use the answer. Edit your question and add the new information.